# rails polymorphic url params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I like polymorphic style url very much, so I can write

```
link_to 'New taste', [:new, :taste]
```

instead of

```
link_to 'New taste', new_taste_path
```

But is it possible to add query parameters to first one without using `polymorphic_url`/`polymorphic_path`?

Comment: You mean that `link_to 'New taste', [:new, :taste], :a_param => 'param'` is not possible?

Comment: @Yannis: no, this adds attribute to anchor tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - you can pass it like so:

```
link_to 'New taste', [[:new, :taste], :a_param => 'param']
```

Comment: Seems that it is available only in rails ~> 4.1

Answer (score 12):

No. When you pass an Array to these methods (`link_to`, `redirect_to`, etc) the url argument is passed directly to `url_for`, which itself calls `polymorphic_path` with a single argument. As you stated `polymorphic_path` allows params to be passed as the second argument, but they cannot be passed as in the first argument.

In order to pass params and use polymorphic routing you have to use `polymorphic_path` / `polymorphic_url` like so:

```
link_to 'New taste', polymorphic_path([:new, :taste], :spiciness => :on_fire)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is more this syntax on Rails >= 4.2:

```
link_to 'New taste', [:new, :taste, { a_param: 'param' }]
```